# How to select and move list of files without explicitly selecting them individually

Tags: powershell, batch-file, full-text-search, move

I have 300 pdf files in a folder in Windows10. The pdf files are named as "1.pdf","2.pdf","3.pdf"......"300.pdf".
I also have a list of 50 random file names(all file names are between 1 and 300) in txt file such as "2.pdf","13.pdf",....
I want to select the specified files mentioned in txt file from the folder and move it to another folder. Is there a way to do it quickly and at once without selecting each individual file and moving it

Comment: Added tags for batch-file and powershell and removed pdf for more appropriate audience.

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell you could do something like

```
gc txtfile.txt | %{ move $_ destination }
```

... which would `gc` or get the contents of txtfile.txt, then for each line, move linefromtxtfile to destination.

Answer (score 0):

The `FOR` command with the `/F` option can be used to read a file. Then you can use the move command to move it to the destination directory.

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN ("myfile.txt") DO MOVE "%%~G" "destination"
```

The `USEBACKQ` option is needed if your text file name has spaces or special characters in it.  The `DELIMS` option is needed so that it does not tokenize the data inside the text file.

This also assumes that your PDF files exist in the same folder as the batch file or the text file lists the relative or absolute paths to the files.

Destination would be an absolute path or relative path depending on your needs.